# np.vectorize local variable (?) referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I am working on a python code where I want to make some modifications to datetime.datetime instances. I am capable of making the code work, yet I do not understand why, I just gave what the error asked for.

```
def ts_round(ts,lev,p):
    sum = False
    hour = 0
    minute = 0
    second = 0

    if 'hour' is lev:
        a = ts.hour // p

        if (ts.hour%p)>=(p*0.5):
            a += 1

        hour = a * p
        minute = ts.minute
        second = ts.second

        if hour == 24: #si llega a 24 hay que sumar un dia
            new_ts = dt.datetime(ts.year,ts.month,ts.day,hour-1,ts.minute,ts.second)
            new_ts = new_ts + dt.timedelta(hours=1)
            sum = True

    elif 'minute' is lev:
        a = ts.minute // p

        if (ts.minute%p)>=(p*0.5):
            a += 1

        minute = a * p
        second = ts.second
        hour = ts.hour

        if minute == 60: #si llega a 60 hay que sumar una hora
            new_ts = dt.datetime(ts.year,ts.month,ts.day,ts.hour,minute-1,ts.second)
            new_ts = new_ts + dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
            sum = True

    elif 'second' is lev: #si llega a 60 hay que suma un minuto
        a = ts.second // p

        if (ts.second%p)>=(p*0.5):
            a += 1

        second = a * p
        hour = ts.hour
        minute = ts.minute

        if second == 60:
            new_ts = dt.datetime(ts.year,ts.month,ts.day,ts.hour,ts.minute,second-1)
            new_ts = new_ts + dt.timedelta(seconds=1)
            sum = True

    if sum:
        return new_ts
    else:
        return dt.datetime(ts.year,ts.month,ts.day,hour,minute,second)
```

This works perfectly if I do not comment 
'hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0' at the beginning (as it is on this post). Could you please explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what arguments you pass to the function. If `lev` does not happen to be a string object with value `'hour'`, `'minute'`, or `'second'` the variables are never initialized but you use them in the last line. You most likely want to use `==` for comparison instead of `is` in the three `if` statements.